# Can you decrease computational time of this matlab code?

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x

```
k=3000
UnqLab = unique(TrainingLabels)
n = length(UnqLab)
count=hist(TrainingLabels,UnqLab); 
num = 1;
for i = 1:n
    fprintf('\n %i',i)
    nn = count(i)
    for j = 1:nn
        NTrainingFeatures(num,:) = TrainingFeatures(num,ranking(i,1:k))
        num = num +1;
    end
end
```

Here *TrainingLabels* is of size 21,000 * 1 and contain 257 labels in sorted order. For example 001,001,001,001,001,001.....002,002,002.......257,257.

*TrainingFeatures* is of size 21,000 * 4096 containg some values.

*ranking* is of size 257*4096. *ranking* contains the rank for example (3076,456,765,4000,87,5,.....). This is how first row looks like. This means that entry of all the first label at 3076 in *TrainingFeatures*  has given first rank.

This code takes too much computation tme(in days). Can there be any way so that it takes less time. Code in Matlab or Python would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general in MATLAB you want to avoid loops. In particular, it looks like your biggest issue is your inner loop; instead of stepping through `count(i)` of items, it would be faster to copy the whole block at once. This should be possible because it looks like you are taking the same sized chunk of TrainingFeatures each time (neither i nor k is loop-dependent). So you should be able to do something like

```
NTrainingFeature(num:num+count(i),:) = TrainingFeatures(num:num+count(i),ranking(i,1:k));
num = num + count(i) + 1;
```

I would definitely test this out (perhaps on a subset of your data or smaller matrices) to make sure everything lines up properly. Without access to your code to test, I may have made a mistake in setting up the indices, or perhaps the matrix shapes don't match. If you are having trouble getting your matrix indices and shapes to line up, you can try using `reshape()` or using single-index calling.

Comment: If you found it helpful, do you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: New here.. so didn't know that it is also an option.

Comment: No worries, it just helps show that the question has been answered in case it comes up in anyone's search. Welcome to Stack Overflow!